# ploting route on bing maps for WP7 using an observable collection of geocoordinates

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, geolocation, bing-maps

hi i'm working on an app that tracks a user saving their location and saving the results into an observable collection of a session class containing geocoordinates.

My question is now that i have a bunch of coordinates how do i plot a visible rout on a (bing)map with them ie plot from each coordinate to the next for **many** ie the whole session (not just a to b).

thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use following API:

```
MapPolyline polyline = new MapPolyline();
polyline.Stroke = stroke;
polyline.StrokeThickness = strokeThinkness;
polyline.Opacity = opacity;
polyline.Locations = locationsList;

MyMap.Children.Add(polyline);
```

Where locationsList is:

```
var locationsList = new LocationCollection();
locationsList.Add(new GeoCoordinate(latitude1, longtitude1, altitude1));
locationsList.Add(new GeoCoordinate(latitude2, longtitude2, altitude2));
locationsList.Add(new GeoCoordinate(latitude3, longtitude3, altitude3));
```

Actually, locationsList is your polyLine.

Comment: is altitude a requirement?, i was kinda hoping to use a a normal observable collection with geocoordinates as an array.

Comment: No, it's not required. LocationCollection inherits itself from ObservableCollection<GeoCoordinate> and it's not sealed. So, you can inherit your type from LocationCollection and use it as wrap to your ObservableCollection.

Answer (score 0):

This API works with BingMaps silverlight control if I'm right. Is this possible in the Bing Maps SOAP Services
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc980922.aspx. I have application that just call SOAP service and download generated image (no silverlight, no javascript), bu i cannot find any equivalent API that renders polygon on the map using the SOAP web service.